# Seeing how c++11 functions are implemented

Tags: c++, c++11

there are some nice functionalities in c++11 however, i would like to port some of them to old c++ code, so is the source-code available of some functions? Like std::to_string ? I just would like to know how they did it.

thanks!

Comment: Check the sources of your standard library implementation.

Comment: use `boost`, most of the new functionality was first implemented in boost first. look at `boost::lexical_cast` it should be close to `std::to_string`.

Comment: @andre: No, far from it. `boost::lexical_cast` uses stringstreams and works for all types that overload the respective operators, while `std::to_string` only works for fundamental types and uses `sprintf`.

Comment: @Xeo - `std::to_string` uses `sprintf` in its specification; it typically does **not** use it in its implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementation specifics of the C++11 spec is dependent on your choice of standard library. For example, [libc++ for LLVM](http://libcxx.llvm.org/) or [libstdc++ for GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/libstdc++/).

You can review the source of those libraries to find what you seek. Be aware that some of the code that implements C++11 features might rely on newer language features than your target, so there's a chance that it won't be a direct copy-and-paste.

Also, remember to respect the license terms of whichever library you borrow from.